# The bootstrap features of checkbox not working when done using jquery append

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, bootstrap-4

The Bootstrap works perfectly fine in html section for the checkbox, but when I use it in the JavaScript section to append a tag, it doesn't work.

I am unable to find any solution.
I want the way it works in html, it to work in the same way when adding with java script.

The bootstrap is not getting used for the checkbox

```
let addItem = (value) => {
  $("#todo").append(`<li>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">${value}</label> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>
  </li>`);
}
```

Comment: When are you calling the function ? Can you share that code..also the code where you are adding the bootstrap files.

Comment: the link to the project is   https://github.com/Shefali-Upadhyay/todoApp

Comment: i have removed the bootstrap. I have one more issue. if i complete change the code the es6 i get an error when`$('#todo').on('click', '.delete', () => {
  $(this).parent().remove();});` gets converted to es5 a variable is declared `var _this = void 0; `.     I need help to change the code completely to es6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#todo').on('click', '.delete', () => { $(this).parent().remove();});
```

You are using an arrow function as the callback.Arrow functions don't bind the 'this' variable by default.What you need to do is use the function declaration for the callback.The following would work

```
$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  console.log("this", this);
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .remove();
});
```

That being said,if you still want to use arrow functions for the callback,you could specify the callback with the event parameter as follows which will also work

```
$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", event => {
  console.log("this", event);
  $(event.currentTarget)
    .parent()
    .remove();
});
```

Also,since you are using Babel in npm run build, it will convert the ES6 code to ES5 implementation so that all browsers which may not support ES6 javascript up and until now will be able to run your code without errors.

For further reading on the usage of arrow functions, refer the following article.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Comment: how can i change the code to javascript from jquery    ```$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", event => {
  console.log("this", event);
  $(event.currentTarget)
    .parent()
    .remove();
});```

Comment: That is just a matter of reading up the DOM  api to find the actual method being used under the hood of jquery.The closest method would do the trick.

document.getElementById("todo").addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.target.closest("li").remove();
});

Comment: Please remember to upvote if the answer helped you.

Comment: Did the solution help you ??

Comment: i want the li to be deleted on clicking the button delete but not by clicking the li.

Comment: https://github.com/Shefali-Upadhyay/todoApp                                                                  here is the link with your code but when I click on the li section the li gets removed, instead what I want is when I click on the delete button, the li tag needs to be removed.                                                                                                           please have a check as you will be able to see in the code properly

Comment: due to this, i am unable to use the checkbox functionality

Comment: You only had to check whether the target originated from within the button inside the event handler

if (event.target.closest(".btn-danger")) {
    event.target.closest("li").remove();
  }

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that bootstrap has already been applied when the html was rendered and it does not reapply after your javasript executes (adding the section)